# Access2007 OleDbConnection over network share persists although share is deletedH

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, ms-access-2007

I've encountered a quite strange behavior of ADO.NET / Access 2007.

I run my C# 2008 program (target framework .NET 2.0) on PC1.
PC1 has a network share on PC2 (\PC2\Temp mapped as X:)
On PC2 in Temp there is the access database file xy.mdb

The program opens a OleDbConnection to X:\xy.mdb. Works fine.

Then while the program is still running I drop the share on PC2.
(Windows Explorer on PC1 tells me the share X: is lost)
I renamed the database file on PC2, so no new connection should be possible.

But the program can still query the database ! 
(via OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() or ExecuteNonQuery())

Has anyone an explanation for me ?
Is the whole database latched ?
And can I prevent this so that I get an OleDbException when the share is dropped and I try to query the no longer available database ?

Thanks for any help,
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue with the following code and a sample access db...not matter how I tried (sahre or mapped drive) i always got the exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The
>   Microsoft Jet database engine cannot
>   find the input table or query
>   'somejunk'.  Make sure it exists and
>   that its name is spelled correctly.

which is expected. You should re-examine you environment to be 100%.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AccessOverShare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int ct = 0;

            using(OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                //oleDbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\127.0.0.1\\share\\test.mdb.";
                oleDbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\\test.mdb.";
                oleDbConnection.Open();

                using(OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = oleDbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText = "select junkid, junktext from somejunk";

                    using (OleDbDataReader oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                    {
                        ct = 0;         
                        while(oleDbDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            ct++;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0:0000}", oleDbDataReader["junkid"]);
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(ct);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("kill the share then press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();

                using (OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = oleDbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText = "select junkid, junktext from somejunk";

                    using (OleDbDataReader oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                    {
                        ct = 0;
                        while (oleDbDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            ct++;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0:0000}", oleDbDataReader["junkid"]);
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(ct);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer and efforts. You're right, I get the 'table not found' error message when the share is lost but only working under .NET 3.5.

Comment: Working with .NET 2.0 I get the mentioned strange behavior. I'm not able to solve this issue and will therefor update to .NET 3.5 (cutting the .NET 2.0 trunk although they wished W2k compatibility). Again, thanks for your help